# UML: Including static functions

Tags: uml, java-native-interface, static-methods

Is there a standard way in UML to model several static methods (not part of a class) that interact with objects?  I'm working on a project that uses the JNI (Java Native Interface) to support C++ code on Android.

I was planning on simply treating the collection of functions as another class, but feel like there has to be a better approach.  Should I ignore the JNI entirely and just include the Java class they represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some circumstances, a module, or, namespace can be considered an "object".

You could "encapsulate" your library with non object functions as an "object", and addan stereotype.

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|..........................<<library>>......................|
|.............................Strings.......................|
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|..+...String:..Date2Str(Date Value)........................|
|..+...String:..Mid(String Source, int Index, int Count)....|
|..+...String:..Reverse(String Source)......................|
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally, UML adopts an OO paradigm.  So it doesn't provide for 1st class functions.  Therefore the only way to model functions is to use methods (either class- or instance based).

The only other option is to reify the functions, i.e. cleate a class for each.  However I'm not sure that's really what you're after.

> I was planning on simply treating the
>   collection of functions as another
>   class

That's probably what I'd have suggested.

> Should I ignore the JNI entirely and
>   just include the Java class they
>   represent?

Depends on what you're trying to show in the model.  Is it important for the audience to understand the functions are called through JNI?  Or conversely, is the purpose more of a "domain model" (i.e. showing the conceptual entities and how they relate and abstracting implementation language choices)?

hth.

Answer (score 0):

UML is a modeling language for **Object Oriented Systems**. So it does not have any construct for standalone static functions.

You may Create a Facade class for your  static methods and  show the interaction of that Facade and Java classes .

But anyway first you should ask:

> What kind of benefit will i get by showing those on my UML diagrams?

If UML does not help you "for your benefit", use other tools. Even if your aim is to show your internal structure to others, pick up an editor show programatically your infrastructure, record that as video then serve it to audience.